# Graphing 3D equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing a computer science assignment but it requires me to understand how to graph a function like $f(x,y) = x - 3y + 3$. Can someone explain to me how to graph this function in the $xyz$ plane?

Comment: Consider the intersection of the function with several different planes, like level curves.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways this expression might be read; I think your assignment wants the second one below, but I should probably mention both.

Since $x - 3y + 3$ only depends on $x$ and $y$ , it is not in itself three-dimensional.  This would simply be a line in the xy-plane , which we can write as  $ x - 3y = -3$ . Its intercepts are given by

**x-intercept** $(y = 0)$ **:**  $ \ x - 3 \cdot 0 = -3 \ \Rightarrow \ x = -3 \ \Rightarrow \ (-3 , 0 )$ ;

**y-intercept** $(x = 0)$ **:**  $ \ 0 - 3 y = -3 \ \Rightarrow \ y = 1 \ \Rightarrow \ (0 , 1 )$ .

The line represented by this equation passes through these two points.

If this is supposed to represent something in three-dimensional space (BTW, there isn't an $xyz$ *plane*), notice that $z$ is not specified in your function, or the line equation, *at all*.  This means $z$ may have *any* value, so the line we've constructed is reproduced directly "above and below" itself at every "level" for $z$.  So you can imagine sweeping the line "up and down" vertically (perpendicularly to the xy-plane) forever; in other words, the function describes a "vertical" plane in three-dimensional space.

All right, having said that, there is another interpretation if what is meant is $f(x,y) = z = x - 3y + 3 $ (I think *this* may be what you're being asked to graph).  We could write this as $ \ x - 3y - z + 3 = 0 \ $ or $ \ x - 3y - z = -3 $ .  This is also a plane in three-dimensional space, but now it is "tilted" with respect to the three coordinate planes.  We can find the three intercepts where it crosses the coordinate axes; two of these are in the xy-plane, so they are analogous to what we've already worked out:

**x-axis intercept** $(y = 0 , z = 0)$ **:**  $ \ x - 3 \cdot 0 - 0 = -3 \ \Rightarrow \ x = -3 \ \Rightarrow \ (-3 , 0 , 0 )$ ;

**y-axis intercept** $(x = 0 , z = 0)$ **:**  $ \ 0 - 3 y - 0 = -3 \ \Rightarrow \ y = 1 \ \Rightarrow \ (0 , 1 , 0 )$ ;

**z-axis intercept** $(x = 0 , y = 0)$ **:**  $ \ 0 - 3 \cdot 0 - z = -3 \ \Rightarrow \ z = 3 \ \Rightarrow \ (0 , 0 , 3 )$ .

Here's a picture of that, where I've tried to angle things so you can see the intercepts easily. [The positive x-direction points nearly toward you, the positive y-direction off to the right, and positive-z is "up".]

[image]